# Gradient Descent for Linear Regression fails to work beta parameters are initialized as zero or one

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

Here is the dummy data for y = mpg and x = hp

```
import numpy as np

mpg = np.array([13,14,15,15,16,17,18,18,19,20])
hp = np.array([200,195,185,178,165,160,155,151,145,130])

# funcion de aprendizaje
def Predecir(b0,b1,x):
    return b0 + (b1 * x)
```

Here is the GD implementation for a single X variable.

```
def GD(X, y, _b0=0, _b1=0, iteraciones=100, alfa=0.0001):
historico = []
m = float(len(y))
for i in range(iteraciones):

    # predecir con los coeficientes actuales
    h0 = Predecir(_b0, _b1, X)

    # perdida
    perdida = h0 - y

    # se estima el costo
    costo = np.sum(perdida ** 2) / (2 * m)

    # almacenenamos todos los costos
    historico.append(costo)

    # calculo del gradiente
    b0_gradiente = np.sum(perdida) / m
    b1_gradiente = np.sum(perdida * X) / m

    # calculo final
    _b0 = _b0 - alfa * b0_gradiente
    _b1 = _b1 - alfa * b1_gradiente

# se retorna las betas, el costo final y el 
# historico de costos
return _b0, _b1, costo, historico
```

Then you can test this with beta parameters at zero:

```
b0, b1, costo, hist = GD(hp, mpg, 0, 0, iteraciones=100, alfa=0.00001)
print(b0,b1,costo)
```

this fails to converge to the required values (b0 = 38.99, b1=-0.0991)
then If I trick the initial betas to be 40 and 5, the GD gets a good guess...

```
b0, b1, costo, hist = GD(hp, mpg, 40, 5, iteraciones=100, alfa=0.00001)
print(b0,b1,costo)
```

Any help highly appreciated. 
Thanks guys! :)

PS: Also note that the data , if plotted shows a negative slope.

Comment: Because you have observed on the plot  that the slope is negative, you already know that the initial parameter estimate for "b1" should be negative.

Comment: That does not work. What happens is that when b0 = 0, b1 = 0, with 10 iterations and a alpha (alfa = 0.0005), the cost is reduced from 138 to 8.9, but the calculated betas are 0.0008, b1=0.009. Initializing b1 as -1 has no significant effect.

Comment: Initializing b0  = 2 * np.max(mpg) and b1 = 0, seems to work much better with a cost of 0.45, b0:39.9, b1: -0.14, but not sure if this is a reliable initialization